# How do I add text to an existing formula based on the value of a different cell?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, edit

I have a spreadsheet that keeps track of monthly expenses. With each month being a new sheet. I'll use A1 as an example of the cell already containing a formula and I want to be able to enter the month's name into a cell, run the macro and have it:
A. Add a new sheet with the name being the new month's name referenced from a different cell (OVERVIEW!$O$3)
B. Add "+(NEWMONTH!$A$1)" to the end of an existing formula

If someone could please leave some code using the following info that'd be amazing!

Formula to be edited is on sheet titled OVERVIEW in cell B1
Month will be entered on sheet OVERVIEW in cell O3

Here's what the formula looks like and what i want it to look like after running the macro.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCdQ6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYDVZ.jpg)

Comment: Hi @dev'n, firstly I would like to tell you that it is not a good practice to post code in an image, you can read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask quite a lot about questions. Now in your problem I see that you always add the cell Q3. So a VBA Function could be written that would add cell Q3 from any sheets that have some characteristic (which you will define) for example having the word "month_To_Add" in cell Q2

Answer (score 1):

As I describe in comment:

```
Public Function addCell() As Variant
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In Worksheets
   'IN NEXT LINE INSTEAD Q2 YOU CAN USE ANY CELL
   'AND INSTEAD OF "month_To_Add" CAN USE ANYTHING YOU WANT
      If ws.Range("Q2") = "month_To_Add" Then
         addCell = addCell + ws.Range("Q3")
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

and use it instead of the formula:

```
=addCell()
```